# I'm using a cursor to navigate through my internal folders, but the folders are empty?

Tags: java, android, storage, cursors

I am trying to find all of the folders in my internal storage which contain Images.  To do this I am using a cursor. The cursor is not null, it is empty, is there a different space i should be looking at to find these folders?

```
        imageFolders = new ArrayList<String>();

        String[] projection = new String[]{
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN};
        System.out.println("Print progress: Created String Projection");
        System.out.println("Print progress: " + projection[0] + " " + projection[1] + " " + projection[2] + " " + projection[3]);

        Uri imageUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI ;
        System.out.println("Print progress: images uri " + imageUri);
        final String orderBy = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN;
        System.out.println("Print progress: orderBy " + orderBy);

        Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(imageUri, projection, // Which columns to return
                null, // Which rows to return (all rows)
                null, // Selection arguments (none)
                orderBy + " DESC" // Ordering
        );
        System.out.println("Print progress: cursor created");
        ArrayList<String> imagePath;



        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            System.out.println("Print progress: entered cursor"
            );
            String bucket, date;

            int bucketColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);
            System.out.println("Print progress: bucketColumn: " + bucketColumn);
            int dateColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN);
            System.out.println("Print progress: dateColumn: " + dateColumn);
            do {
                bucket = cur.getString(bucketColumn);
                System.out.println("Print progress: bucket: " + bucket);

                date = cur.getString(dateColumn);
                System.out.println("Print progress: date: " + date);
                if (!imageFolders.contains(bucket)) {
                    imageFolders.add(bucket);
                }
                imagePath = listImageByFolder.get(bucket);
                if (imagePath == null) {
                    imagePath = new ArrayList<String>();
                }
                imagePath.add(cur.getString(cur
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)));
                listImageByFolder.put(bucket, imagePath);
            } while (cur.moveToNext());
        }
        System.out.println("Print progress: Found the Internal Image Folders");
        return imageFolders;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by *refuses to moveToFirst* you mean that the `if` block is skipped because `moveToFirst()` returns `false`. That happens when the `Cursor` is empty:

> public abstract boolean moveToFirst ()
>
> Move the cursor to the first row. This method will return false if the
>   cursor is empty. - Android [API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor#moveToFirst()).

Comment: I think that you are right, and I have amended the question appropriately. I am still confused as to why the cursor is empty, do you have any insight?

Comment: In a nutshell, the query is not returning any results. According to the API, neither `query()` nor `moveToFirst()` throw an exception, which means it's not clear whether there's an error in your query's syntax or if the data you're looking for doesn't exist in the place you're looking for it. You'll just have to dig in a troubleshoot. Welcome to software engineering :)